# Is it possible to request a Vertex AI endpoint from another GCP project?

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I trained a model on GCP Vertex AI, and deployed it on an endpoint.

I am able to execute predictions from a sample to my model with this python code https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/predictions/online-predictions-automl#aiplatform_predict_image_classification_sample-python

It works within my GCP project.

My question is, is it possible to request this endpoint from another GCP project ? If I set a service account and set IAM role in both projects ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible. For example you have Project A and Project B, assuming that Project A hosts the model.

- Add service account of Project B in Project A and provide at least `roles/aiplatform.user` predefined role. See [predefined roles](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/general/access-control#predefined-roles) and look for `roles/aiplatform.user` to see complete roles it contains.
- This role contains **aiplatform.endpoints.*** and **aiplatform.batchPredictionJobs.*** as these are the roles needed to run predictions.

  > See [IAM permissions for Vertex AI](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/general/iam-permissions)
  >
  > | Resource | Operation | Permissions needed |
  > | --- | --- | --- |
  > | batchPredictionJobs | Create a batchPredictionJob | aiplatform.batchPredictionJobs.create (permission needed on the parent resource) |
  > | endpoints | Predict an endpoint | aiplatform.endpoints.predict (permission needed on the endpoint resource) |

With this set up, Project B will be able to use the model in Project A to run predictions.

NOTE: Just make sure that the script of Project B points to the resources in Project A like `project_id` and `endpoint_id`.

Comment: Thanks, it's resolved